# Check how many entities where read from a query

Tags: database, logging, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

How can I check how many entities in total where read by datastore when I run a Query?

I'm trying to calculate the costs of my queries. Is there something I can check in stackdriver? I found something under App engine but that gives me for all queries. I would like to see for a specific one.

Comment: I raised this feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66347398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist. You'll have to instrument your code to log the number of entities returned from the query in question.

Comment: are the entities returned same as the entities read in datastore?

Comment: Yes, except if you use OFFSET. I believe we tell you the number of skipped results in that case (which maybe be between zero and OFFSET).

Comment: I see. Any plans to add this in the future without us going in code level to get these metrics?